# how to import the module 'pyclipper' when using python3

Tags: python, import, importerror, pyclipper

I am training a CNN model (scene text detection) and there is a error

`Import Error: no module named pyclipper`

I have tryed

`pip3 install --default-timeout=100 pyclipper`

as what i did when facing other similiar import error. but it kept retrying, seeming that there are no such module for me to install

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple/

Collecting pyclipper

  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) 
after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f52e1c137f0>, 
'Connection to 114.212.86.238 timed out. (connect timeout=100.0)')': /simple/pyclipper/
```

how can i solve this? thank you so much

Comment: please post the error message when `pip3 install`

Comment: it just keep printing the 'WARNING: Retrying' message every few seconds as shown above 

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any proxies you should disable it when trying to `pip3 install`.
Mays it's just your company's firewall.